# Fix annoying warnings about CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE

Tags: cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I am building some components on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, with ROS fuerte, rtt build from source from latest master (e95fe17c5ef504b03785818260d212d54e5bdf54).  I am building components with rosmake, and sometimes I get the following annoying warning during build:

```
CMake Warning:
Manually-specified variables were not used by the project:

  CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE
```

I ran rgrep, and verified that none of our CMakeLists are defining this variable.  It does appear in the CMakeCache files, which I assume is what is throwing the warning.

Should I silence these warnings, and how?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/48243/fix-annoying-warnings-about-cmake_toolchain_file/) by [drewm1980](https://answers.ros.org/users/1742/drewm1980/) on ROS Answers with karma: 258 on 2012-11-13

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The variable is set by `cmake.mk` which can be found in `/opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros/core/mk`. The file `/opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros/core/rosbuild/rostoolchain.cmake` contains more information about the purpose of the file. I think it has something to do with cross compilation.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-11-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1